# How long does it take for the Curiosity cube to get updated? Is there more than one cube?

Tags: curiosity

In the new Android/iOS app/game/experiment called Curiosity, how long does it take for the cube to update?  I did a ton of work in one section of the cube and I carved in my initials.  Then I got on my wife's Android device, to see if I could see my work on another device.  I couldn't find my stuff.  In fact, it looks like an entirely different cube --- there was absolutely nothing in any area that looked remotely like what it looked like on my device.  So I thought maybe it would take a while for my work to get updated.  So we waited an entire day, and revisited the cube on both devices.  Once again nothing looked similar at all.  We zoomed into the exact same location, and waited for a few minutes in case it needed to catch up or something.  Indeed, after a few minutes the cube DID refresh (bonus question: how long does the in-game refresh take to happen after you start the app?), but it was entirely different for both devices.

I already considered and checked to make sure that we were really looking at the same side of the cube, in the same location.  We checked several times over the course of a couple of days, and the only conclusions I can come to are that either, A) the game is lying, and just randomly making it appear that the cube is being chipped away at by other people, or B) there is more than one cube.

What's the deal?  I'm already aware that they have been having issues (coins being lost, etc.), but I have not seen anything regarding what I'm talking about.

Comment: It's supposed to be one Cube. 22 Cans have been having server issues with Curiosity, so likely you're running into sync bugs. That's a *huge* sync bug if so, but the alternative is that they've been lying about the entire premise of the game. I suppose that's possible, but unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the rules of the competition (in game click the arrow, then "I")... Rule 5 states: "There is only one Cube in the world and the state of the Cube is stored on our servers. Subject to latency, the Cube appears the same to all those in the world taking part."  Although my husband and I just got on and he sees two new pictures that he didn't see last night (they were red) whereas I still see them as red. Chalking this up to latency issues for the time being.